# php build query username and password and check result

Tags: php, sql

i would like to ask you about my database query 
i have this table `admin_table` in my data base

```
tag id       name           password       profession 
xxxxxx     Jhon Begly         123            admin
```

i build a php page to insert a user name and password 
i need to check the user name and password that i entered with its profession if its valid then proceed with a new page as bellow

$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin_table WHERE name='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";

so how can i check profession in the same query above
any update will be highly appreciated

Comment: Learn about prepared statements and bind variables

Comment: You should not save clear text passwords in your database. Encrypt the passwords first and save the hash. Then, to authenticate, encrypt the user input and compare to the saved hash. Also, to prevent "SQL injection attacks", do not concatenate strings to build SQL queries, use "prepared statements" instead.

Comment: What do you mean, "check"? `where profession='user'`? Or get the profession information back into client-side code?

Comment: i want to enter username and password and check these entry if its related to profession= admin then login will success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin_table WHERE name='".$username."' 
        AND password='".$password."' AND profession = 'admin'";
```

If you get a result row back, you matched all three columns. If zero rows, it failed to match at least one. Not really sure your use case.

I also agree with other commenters that this is far from best practices in several ways.

Comment: ok my friend its work now i just want to try it and will take advise from you and from others in consideration thanx

Answer (score 0):

Where are you validating the profession?  If it is in another table... use

```
INNER JOIN profession_table as pt 
ON pt.some_column
```

right after the from part of your query

Comment: let me tell you, i want to enter username and password and check these entry if its related to profession= admin then login will success